# Awk results not working

Tags: shell, unix, awk

---

### Hi I have a text file with values

```
A VAL|1|2|3|

C VAL|2|2|3|

D VAL|1|2|3|

[No space between lines]

I want to replace the values in the above as per the first col i.e A VAL,C  
VAL,D VAL,
so I want to 

1. replace 3 from A VAL row 
2. replace 2 value from C VAL row.
3. replace 1 value from D VAL row.
Basically I want to modify the above values by using AWK as AWK helps 
     treating csv , pipe delimited files
So I tried by using AWK command as
```

`enter code here`

```
`awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {if ($1="A") sub($4,"A1") ;elseif ($1="C") sub        
            ($2,"B1"); print }' myval.txt`
```

*But I am getting wrong results *

> C|B1|2|A1|B1C
>
> C|B1|2|A1|B1C
>
> C|B1|2|3|B1C

```
 >The fisrt column itself is geting replace and the substitution is at wrong
 >position.
```

**Expected output is **

```
A VAL|1|2|A1|
C VAL|2|2|B1|
D VAL|1|2|3|
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the formatting more consistent.

Comment: @anubhava I want to change the value of row starting with A VAL and C VAL not the D VAL.So they must be unchanged

Answer (score 2):

You can try this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} $1 ~ /^A/{$(NF-1)="A1"} $1 ~ /^C/{$(NF-1)="B1"} 1' file.csv

A VAL|1|2|A1|
C VAL|2|2|B1|
D VAL|1|2|3|
```

Comment: Thanks !!! this works partially .Sorry to say that But "A VAL" , "C VAL" , "D VAL" is dynamic. The only constant in these strings are A,C,D

Comment: ok I changed it to look for values starting with `A` or `C` in `$1` now. It is always better to clarify requirements in question

Answer (score 0):

awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}{if(substr($1,0,1)=="A")sub($3,"A1",$3);else if(substr($1,0,1)=="C")sub($3,"B1",$3);else if(substr($1,0,1)=="D")sub($3,"3",$3);print }' inputtext.txt > outtext.txt

This is working fine